# How can I verify that a uniformed cop is a real cop?

Tags: police, connecticut

In the state of Connecticut, when a uniformed officer or officers approach, are they required to provide identification showing they are police officers upon request?

Anyone can buy a uniform off the internet and say they are a cop. My question specifically pertains to safety.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.... you have question marks in places that makes what you're asking confusing.

Comment: Sorry. My question is:In the state of Connecticut, when a uniform officer or officers approach, are they required to provide identification showing they are police officers upon request?

Comment: Probably in some circumstances, yes, and in others, no.

Comment: Which makes sense for an undercover not to blow it up like that. But a uniform cop is a little different. There is no way to tell from appearance if the uniform officer is a cop or a psycho "cabin by the lake" imposter.

Comment: I found this           https://www.lawadvisor.com/questions/do-police-officers-have-to-identify-themselves-if-asked And https://www.google.com/amp/boingboing.net/2015/02/25/think-you-have-the-right-to-de.html/amp.

Comment: Particularly related: https://law.stackexchange.com/q/5563/10 ... and many more related questions [linked from this one](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/8130/10).

Comment: I'd ask something slightly different: If a man or woman is dressed in a police officer's uniform and claims to be a police officer and therefore to have special rights, what can you ask for them to give as evidence, and at which point can you assume they are not a police officer?

Comment: Don't American police officers carry a wallet with their photo ID card and shiny badge? They do on TV.

Answer (score 6):

This is a no win situation. People who try to stop in a safe public place fearing that the cop may be an imposter [risk prosecution for resisting arrest](http://web.archive.org/web/20170714053740/https://www.allthatsfab.com/articles/society/cop-signals-woman-pull-over-she-drives-public-place-huge-mistake). But, no one will offer you any remedy if the cop was an imposter who was victimizing you.

One recommended course of action if you doubt a cop is real is to call 911 as you pull over to confirm that the cop trying to pull you over is real.