# Unknown law enforcement

Tags: united-states, police

During the current protests, there have been numerous reports of unknown/unidentified law enforcement personnel. Do these people have to show credentials if asked? If they give orders (without identifying), can I legally refuse to comply? Understanding that these people are armed, with military gear, so one assumes they are law enforcement, but what are my rights?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(When) are police required to identify themselves?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/5563/when-are-police-required-to-identify-themselves)